# Eigenvalues of linear map

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $q$ prime $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and for fixed $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q^n} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i b_i :c_i \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, define $M_\alpha : (\mathbb{F}_{q})^n \rightarrow (\mathbb{F}_{q})^n$ be the map that represents multiplication by $\alpha$. 
Also, consider another linear map $T : (\mathbb{F}_{q})^n \rightarrow (\mathbb{F}_{q})^n$ which denotes $\alpha \mapsto \alpha ^q$. What are the eigenvalues of $M_\alpha$ and $T$?
 
For $M_\alpha$ I know that if $x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i :a_i \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$ and $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i b_i :c_i \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, then $M_\alpha (x) = (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i (b_i)^2) + (\sum_{i< j} (a_i c_j + a_jc_i) b_ib_j)$, but I am not sure how to deduce the eigenvalues from here. 

For $T$, I know that $T$ has an eigenvalue of $1$ since $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q}, T(\alpha) = \alpha$ but I believe this eigenspace has only dimension 1 and I am not sure if there are additional eigenvalues. 

I am quite stuck. If anything is not clear, please let me know.